# Guardar variables de entorno en un fichero .txt

Tags: java, map

En **Java**, quisiera guardar las **variables de entorno** de mi sistema/PC en un fichero .txt, solicitándome el nombre del **fichero .txt**. ¿Qué nomenclatura tengo que utilizar para guardarlas?

**Código:**

```
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Ejercicio1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion; //Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

        while (!salir) {

            System.out.println("1. Opcion 1");
            System.out.println("2. Opcion 2");
            System.out.println("3. Opcion 3");
            System.out.println("4. Salir");

            try {
                System.out.println("Escribe una de las opciones: ");
                opcion = sn.nextInt();

                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion 1");
                        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
                        Set<String> keys = env.keySet();
                        for (String key : keys) {
                            System.out.println(key + " = " + env.get(key));
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion 2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Has seleccionado la opcion 3");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        salir = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Solo números entre 1 y 4");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Debes insertar un número");
                sn.next();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar la pregunta? ¿A qué te refieres con qué nomenclatura hay que utilizar?

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA No sé si utilizar un objeto de la clase File para utilizar el método write o cómo realizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para escribir datos en un fichero, dispones de varias clases.

En primer lugar, tienes la clase `File`, que te sirve principalmente para comprobar si el fichero ya existe, o para crear uno nuevo.

```
File fichero = new File("rutaFichero");
if (fichero.exists()) {
    // Hacer algo (mensaje de error vs. sobre escribir)
}
else {
    // El fichero no existe, creamos uno nuevo
    fichero.createNewFile();
    // Y trabajamos con el fichero
}
```

Ahora bien, para escribir datos en un fichero tienes la clase abstracta `Writer`, que utilizaremos mediante su implementación en la clase `FileWriter`, que ya permite escribir datos en un fichero.

```
File fichero = new File("rutaFichero");
// Comprobamos si existe como antes
Writer escritor = new FileWriter(fichero);
// ...
for (String key : keys) {
    escritor.append(key);
    escritor.append(" = ");
    escritor.append(env.get(key));
    escritor.append("\n");
}
```